# Market risk factor proxies examples

Tags: risk-management, risk-models, financial-markets

I am reading some corporate documentation, including the notion of market risk factor proxy. Could you provide some examples of risk factors and their proxies?

What I find obvious is the observable ON interest rate as a proxy for instantaneous rate, or the same one for implied volatility. Hope there is a diverse series of examples.